# D3.js ~ placing rectangles with for loop and coloring them

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I need to set up the color legend for a scatterplot. 
I already set up the scale and it's working on the dots in the scatterplot, however what i want to do now is to draw a little square for each color, filled with the color itself, to show the legend of the diagram. 
Something like this at the start of my graph:
[image]

I tried to set up the function to draw them accordingly but failed, here's what I tried:

```
var colore = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, function (d) { return d.Peso; }))
    .range(["#fee0d2","#fcbba1","#fc9272","#fb6a4a","#ef3b2c","#cb181d","#a50f15","#67000d"]);
```

and the function to draw the squares:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(colore.range())
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function (i) { return colore(i); })
    .attr("x", function (i) {for (i=1; i <= colore.range().length; i++) 
        { return (i * 12) + "px"; }
        })
    .attr("y", margin - 8 + "px")
    .attr("width", 8 + "px")
    .attr("height", 8 + "px");
```

This appends to the svg element 8 squares, but stacked onto eachother, like so (the red one):
[image]

So I don't know how to correct my for functions, which I assume are where the errors happen. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not using the `data` bound to each rectangle, but instead looping over all the colors each time. Try something like this:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(colore.range()).enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function (color){ return color; })
    .attr("x", function (color, index){ return (index * 12) + "px"; })
    .attr("y", margin - 8 + "px")
    .attr("width", 8 + "px")
    .attr("height", 8 + "px");
```

The key thing to note is that if you can pass an attribute a function that takes an Object and an index as arguments that will then get applied to each datum. Using this approach, I get this:

[image: example output]

Comment: I solved it and was about to delete it, I didn't need to use the for loops since I already have the data array, will edit the answer now

Comment: @tomtomtom: you can always answer your own question so that if others have the same question later they can see an answer. Or if my solution also works for you, you can upvote/accept that as well :)

Comment: Ok nevermind I'll accept yours as correct, with this edit is valid! Thanks :)